# Using index of to search for multiple characters

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string

In my Arduino project, a string will be received. I understand using `.indexof` to find the placement of a certain character in the string. My problem is that I need to find the first occurrence of any letter A-Z and haven't found any resources regarding using `or`  statements in an `.indexof` aka `string.indexof("a" || "b" ....)`.

Is this something that is not possible using indexof functions and if so is there any function that I can use to solve this! Thanks!

Comment: index is only for one comparison at a time. there's a built-in `isupper(char)`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/. you can find many chars at once using https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/

Comment: You can also use a for loop that checks the value of i (or whatever variable) and then depending on what i is it runs indexof with different letters.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two functions that I hope help in your endeavours. You can supply either a String or a char array and you should get the first position of an alpha character. Returns -1 if not present.

See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/characters/isalpha/

Update:

Thanks to great comments from Edgar & Mat I have updated the functions with best practise and cost improvements.

```cpp
int alphaPos(const char* str)
{
  for (int i = 0; str[i] !=0 ; ++i) {
    if (isAlpha(str[i]))
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
  
  return -1;
}


int alphaPos(const String& str)
{
  return alphaPos(str.c_str());
}

/*
    Usage:

    String bobble = "&&&88434a";
    int x = alphaPos(bobble);

    if (x != -1) 
    {
      ...x has the position in the string
    }
    else
    {
     ...There is no alpha char present.
    }
*/
```

Comment: I suggest passing a `const` reference to the second overload.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, I admit I have much to learn so ask honestly what the benefit is?

Comment: @voidPointer: it indicates to the caller that the function will not modify the passed String. It is good practice. Also you can avoid the `strlen` call (which doubles the cost of the function) - use `str[i] != 0` in the loop condition instead.

Comment: @Mat. Thanks. That strlen tip is pretty cool and will help others too.

Comment: To elaborate on Mat's comment: if you wan to get an idea of _why_ it is considered good practice, see [Const Correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) on the isocpp.org wiki.

Comment: @EdgarBonet That is a good read. Thanks.